# Python DDD implementação de interfaces

Tags: python, typescript, ddd

Seguinte possuo uma dúvida, recentemente tenho estudado um pouco de DDD e achei sensacional, porém todo o código que escrevi foi em Typescript, e algo que me chamou muito a atenção foi o fato de declarar *intefaces* que funcionam como um contrato para os repositórios definindo que tipo de função cada repositório têm e qual o tipo de retorno, por exemplo:

```js
interface IUserRepo{
  createUser(user: User): Promise<void>
  getUser(userId: string): Promise<User>
}
```

Logo em seguida, tendo o repositório com o contrato das operações, vem então a implementação, podendo usar vários tipos de abordagem, como usar um banco de dados, porém todas essas coisas já não são do escopo do domínio, mas na hora de implementar o código fica assim:

```js
import { IUserRepo } from "caminio..ate..IUserRepo.ts"

class MongoDBIMplementation implements IUserRepo {
  //Toda a lógica da implementação para os retornos corretos das funções definidas na interface
}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, há alguma abordagem em Python para isso? Sei que para definir as classes e o domínio é possível usar dataclasses e tudo mais, essa parte eu conheço, mas não me vem a mente uma forma de implementar essa abordagem de repositórios e implementações, gostaria então de saber se alguém já trabalhou/trabalha com DDD em python e como é feito esse procedimento, tem como usar alguma coisa que se aproxime desse implements do typescript para implementar o repositório ou não?

Comment: Tem abordagem similar a interfaces em python, mas o mecanismo é contra produtivo trata-se de [classes ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). Resolver abstração e herança em python fica é mais simples usando mixins(herança de múltiplas de classes) lembrando que classes que herdam múltiplas classes podem ser afetadas pelo problema do diamante.

Comment: Sofri com esse problema de diamante muito em C++, mas quanto a minha dúvida achei a resposta lá na outra, mesmo assim obrigado pelo esclarecimento